# Database Query (while or foreach) with $row->element instead of $row["element"]

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to make a simple script but I want to allow users to use `$row->title` instead of `$row['title']`.

```
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row['FirstName'] . " " . $row['LastName']; //THIS IS THE PROBLEM, SEE BELOW
  echo "<br>";
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

I want to make it  `echo $row->FirstName . " " . $row->LastName` instead of `echo $row['FirstName'] . " " . $row['LastName'];`

Comment: Use [mysqli_fetch_object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php) instead of `mysqli_fetch_array`.

Comment: do you mean [**`mysqli_fetch_object()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php)

Comment: -> operator is used to access objects not the associativeArray/arrays. Since you are fetching the array you can't directly let your users use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use *[mysqli_fetch_object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php)* instead of `mysql_fetch_array` to get result set as an object.

Answer (score 1):

Check [**Manual**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php) for mysqli_fetch_object which return object instead of array. Use following code

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
  echo $row->FirstName . " " . $row->LastName; 
  echo "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

since `->` `operator` is used with objects you need to fetch data in `object` form instead of `array or assoc array`.

```
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
      echo $row->FirstName . " " . $row->LastName; //THIS IS THE PROBLEM, SEE BELOW
      echo "<br>";
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
```